# Flutter : GetX Variable initialise problem in Profile Data

Tags: object, model, profile, state-management, flutter-getx

I am using GetX statemangement on my flutter app. I want to fetch User's Profile data from server. That's Why I create a Profile Model Class and a Controller Screen. But I can't. Here is a problem to initialisation.

**json Response -**

```
{
  "riderId": 1,
  "riderName": "Ramiz Miah",
  "riderContact": "01787656565",
  "riderEmail": "ramiz@hotmail.com",
  "riderImgRef": ""
}
```

**Profile Model**

```
class ProfileModel {
  int? riderId;
  String? riderName;
  String? riderContact;
  String? riderEmail;
  String? riderImgRef;

  ProfileModel(
      {this.riderId,
      this.riderName,
      this.riderContact,
      this.riderEmail,
      this.riderImgRef});

  ProfileModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    riderId = json['riderId'];
    riderName = json['riderName'];
    riderContact = json['riderContact'];
    riderEmail = json['riderEmail'];
    riderImgRef = json['riderImgRef'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['riderId'] = riderId;
    data['riderName'] = riderName;
    data['riderContact'] = riderContact;
    data['riderEmail'] = riderEmail;
    data['riderImgRef'] = riderImgRef;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class ParofileController extends GetxController {
  RxMap<String, dynamic> profileDetails = <String, dynamic>{}.obs;
  //<============= Fetch and Assign DashBoard Today Details List

  void fetchandAssignProfileDetails() async {
    try {
      ProfileApiService().getProfileDetails().then((resp) {
       
          profileDetails.value = resp;
    
      }, onError: (err) {
        debugPrint(err.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**And API Service**

```
class ProfileApiService extends GetConnect {
  Future<ProfileModel?> getProfileDetails() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse("${AppConfig.baseUrl}/Rider/GetRiderDetails");

    var response = await http.get(
      url,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return ProfileModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User Profile');
    }
  }
}
```

And Now my Question is How to Define this variable here (  `RxMap<String, dynamic> profileDetails = <String, dynamic>{}.obs;` ), that's why it's work properly

Comment: may i know why you need to store the ProfileModel object as a map, where you can store it as ProfileModel object easily

Comment: riderName = json['riderName'].toString(); // Set to Type **.toString()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this

```
 Rx<ProfileModel?> profile = ProfileModel().obs;
```

thanks.